# Docker compose: scale both services

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have the following **docker-compose**:

```
version: '2'
services:
    cryptohds:
        image: cryptohds:cryptohds-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT
        environment:
            - APP_SLEEP=10 # gives time for the database to boot before the application
            - SPRING_DATASOURCE_DRIVER_CLASS_NAME=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
            - SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:mysql://cryptohds-mysql:3306/cryptohds?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&useSSL=false
            - SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME=root
            - SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD=cryptohds
    cryptohds-mysql:
        extends:
            file: mysql.yml
            service: cryptohds-mysql
```

As for the **mysql.yml**:

```
version: '2'
services:
    cryptohds-mysql:
        image: mysql:5.7.20
        environment:
            - MYSQL_USER=root
            - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=cryptohds
            - MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes
            - MYSQL_DATABASE=cryptohds
        ports:
            - 3306
        command: mysqld --lower_case_table_names=1 --skip-ssl --character_set_server=utf8 --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp
```

When scaling **cryptohds** they scale fine, but they all use the same **cryptohds-mysql**. I want to scale **cryptohds** and each instance have their own **cryptohds-mysql**.

How can i achieve this? Should they be two services that share a network between them and then scale them individually? 
But in that case how can i use the SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL?

**UPDATE**

I've actually built a docker-compose that does what i need, but it's not dynamic. It specifically creates 2 instances of each, and i want a random number. Is there any other way of doing this dynamically? Or only by a script?

```
version: '2'
services:
    cryptohds:
        image: cryptohds:cryptohds-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT
        environment:
            - APP_SLEEP=10 # gives time for the database to boot before the application
            - SPRING_DATASOURCE_DRIVER_CLASS_NAME=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
            - SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:mysql://cryptohds-mysql:3306/cryptohds?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&useSSL=false
            - SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME=root
            - SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD=cryptohds
    cryptohds-mysql:
        extends:
            file: mysql.yml
            service: cryptohds-mysql
    cryptohds_1:
        image: cryptohds:cryptohds-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT
        environment:
            - APP_SLEEP=10 # gives time for the database to boot before the application
            - SPRING_DATASOURCE_DRIVER_CLASS_NAME=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
            - SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:mysql://cryptohds-mysql_1:3306/cryptohds?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&useSSL=false
            - SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME=root
            - SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD=cryptohds
    cryptohds-mysql_1:
        extends:
            file: mysql.yml
            service: cryptohds-mysql
```

Comment: Even stacks don't scale like that, since they're just independent services. You may need to write something (script or application) to scale them together. Even then, it'll be synchronous waiting for the first to finish

Comment: Do you want the two groups to be completely Independent, or do they all need to be on a single network to communicate between all 4 containers?

Comment: @BMitch, i want each group to be completly independent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To run the containers as completely separate groups, I'd recommending defining them as separate "projects" in `docker-compose`. In swarm mode, the equivalent would be deploying separate "stacks". The project name defaults to your current directory name. You can override that with the `-p` option, e.g.:

```
docker-compose -p cryptohds2 up
```